# An Elementary Convergence Problem in Probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables

> Suppose that $X_1,X_2,...$ are degenerate random variables such that $f_{X_n}$ denotes the mass function of $X_n$.$$f_{X_n}(x)=P(X_n=x)= \begin{cases} 
>       1, & x=2+\dfrac{1}{n} \\
>       0, & otherwise \\
>    \end{cases}
> $$
>   Show that the distribution functions, $F_{X_n}$ converge to the following function $F$. $$F(x)= \begin{cases}0, & x<2\\1,&x\geq2\end{cases}$$

I am getting $$F(x)=\begin{cases}0,&x\leq2\\1,&x>2\end{cases}$$

because none of the $f_{X_n}$ assigns any mass to the point $2$, so $F_{X_n}(2)=0$ for each $n$.

Is this happening because of the right continuity of $F$, which should also be a distribution function of a random variable ? In this case, $F$ turns out to be the d.f. of the  random variable degenerate at $x=2$.

Comment: Do the density functions integrate to 0?  Do they need to be delta functions to integrate to 1?

Comment: No my question is: why should the limit function $F$ necessarily be a distribution function? We can have a situation $F_{X_n}\to F$ where $F$ is not a d.f. At $x=2$ $F_{X_n}=0$ for all $n$. Then it should be that $F(2)=0$ if $F$ is the limit function.

Answer (score 2):

The point of contention is $x{}={}2$ and what happens there. Being careful about how we approach this point of discontinuity for $F(x)$, using a limiting sequence in terms of the $F_n(x)$ and the right continuity of $F(x)$, note that for all $k>0$,
$$
F_n\left(2+\dfrac{1}{k}\right){}={}1\,,\ \ \forall\ n>k\,.
$$

So, for all $k>0$,

$$
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}F_n\left(2+\dfrac{1}{k}\right){}={}1{}={}F\left(2+\dfrac{1}{k}\right)\,.
$$

Therefore,

$$
\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}F_n\left(2+\dfrac{1}{k}\right){}={}1{}={}\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}F\left(2+\dfrac{1}{k}\right){}={}F\left(2+\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\dfrac{1}{k}\right){}={}F\left(2\right)\,.
$$
Consequently, there is a sub-sequence of unique "$n,k$" pairs such that this double limit holds: certainly, the functions $F_n(x)$ tend to $F(2)$ in this sense.

Comment: That is all very fine, but why did you assume that $F$ is necessarily a distribution function? If we take $F$ to be a distribution function then we are done by right continuity. But it is not mentioned that the limit function $F$ is also a distribution function.

Comment: @yedaynara, by definition, $F(x){}={}1\,\forall\ x\ge2$.

Comment: By what definition? So sorry I am not understanding you. $F(x)$ is not given to be a d.f., WE have to check that. But you supposed that $F$ is right continuous. Why is that?

Comment: @yedaynara, The question reads "Show that...converges to the following function $F$. $F=\left\{\begin{array}{c}\\\end{array}\right.\dots$". That is, the question defines the function that you should show the sequence converges to. I make no assumptions about the limiting function of the $F_n$ as they tend towards $x=2$; I simply show that whatever that limiting function's value is, it is the same value as this $F$ the question has already defined for me.

Comment: What if the question just read "Find the limiting function $F$"? Would your answer still be the same?

Comment: @yedaynara, Yes, the limiting value of the $F_n$ as they tend to $x=2$ will still be the same.